# Error :Call to a member function XXXX() on array

Tags: php

Tengo una clase con una funcion que retorna un array

```
function buscarPorComplejo($idComplejo){
  $sql = "SELECT * FROM XXX where id_complejo = '$idComplejo' ";
  $rs = mysql_query($sql) or die("Error en la Busqueda -cabanas-");
  $reg = 0;
  while($row = mysql_fetch_array($rs)){
    $vec["$reg"]["id"] = $row["id"];
    $vec["$reg"]["descripcion"] = $row["descripcion"];
    $vec["$reg"]["cantidadHuespedes"] = $row["cantidad_huespedes"];
    $vec["$reg"]["idComplejo"] = $row["id_complejo"];
    $vec["$reg"]["activo"] = $row["activo"];
    $reg++;
  }
  mysql_free_result($rs);
  if(isset($vec)){
    return $vec;
  }else{
    return false;
  }
}
```

Este array lo guardo en una variable dentro de una iteración.

```
foreach($arrayComplejo as $key=>$complejo){
    $arrayCabana = $cabana->buscarPorComplejo($complejo['id']);
}
```

En la segunda pasada me da el siguiente error:

```
"PHP Fatal error: Call to a member function buscarPorComplejo() on array in ...."
```

Ya probé limpiando la variable con [unset](http://php.net/manual/es/function.unset.php) pero no consigo evitar este error, alguna idea?

Comment: Coloca el error completo para saber la causa exacta, y poder ayudarte de mejor manera.

Comment: Luego del IN solo sigue la ruta del archivo que posee el error y el referer (la url), el error es el que muestro ahí =)

Comment: Comprueba primero si la consulta obtuvo resultados, es posible que estés intentando obtener valores en una posición que no existe _o en datos que no existen_.

Comment: es un foreach....

Comment: dentro del foreach, es la UNICA línea que hay? seguro que no reescribres la variable $cabana posteriormente?

Comment: @Fakux, ¿puedes agregar los resultados que esperas obtener y/o los resultados que has obtenido luego de ejecutar la consulta? Por ejemplo ¿`idComplejo` es igual a `id_complejo`?

Comment: Ahí encontré el error en base a tu consulta, no se declaraba nuevamente PERO hay otro foreach dentro que por alguna razón usaba $cadena igual que el nombre de la instancia de la clase. ( $cabana=>$valor ). Cambie esa variable y salio funcionando!, gracias! @PabloAlcantar

Answer (score 2):

El problema era que dentro del foreach:

```
foreach($arrayComplejo as $key=>$complejo){
    $arrayCabana = $cabana->buscarPorComplejo($complejo['id']);
}
```

Estaba declarada la variable $cabana que se utilizaba como instancia de la clase, cambie el nombre de la variable y salio funcionando con normalidad.

Answer (score 0):

Si ya esta solucionado marca como correcta cualquier respuesta para cerrar la pregunta por favor. Si no puedes marcar la tuya propia, dejo aquí la solución para que pueda cerrarse.

Solucionado por el autor de la pregunta Fakux:

**El problema era que dentro del foreach:**

```
foreach($arrayComplejo as $key=>$complejo){
    $arrayCabana = $cabana->buscarPorComplejo($complejo['id']);
}
```

**Estaba declarada la variable $cabana que se utilizaba como instancia de la clase,**